# Issue with dynamically created variables

Tags: jquery, click, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to dynamically access the different global variables (AvGen.svg1, AvGen.svg2 and so on) in the button event below, but by some reason it doesn't work even though the variable 'svg' becomes the same (e.g. AvGen.svg1) as putting AvGen.svg1 directly into the 'add' method.

How come it doesn't work?

```
AvGen = {

    currSvg: 0,
    svg1: null,
    svg1: null,

    init: function() {
        AvGen.loadSVG();
        AvGen.toolBox();
    },

    loadSVG: function() {
        AvGen.svg1 = [0,0,255.3,298.5,{type:'path',path:'M 35.3 257.2 C 34.4 245.7 45.4 234.1 48.5 223 C 53.6 204.3 55 185 60 166.2 C 69.5 131 69.6 97.1 89.1 65.1 C 103.4 41.7 129.5 5.3 161.3 19.7 C 184.6 30.3 181.3 59.2 188.9 78.9 C 207.5 127.3 228.6 184.8 230.3 237.3 C 231.3 268.6 202.8 261.3 178.2 264 C 149.2 267.1 120 269.6 91 272.2 C 84.2 272.8 75.8 274.2 69 273 C 60.9 271.6 28.9 259.9 31.3 249.2','fill':'#39b54a','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}];
        AvGen.svg2 = [0,0,278.9,314.1,{type:'path',path:'M 32 265 C 31.8 245.2 38 226.9 39.8 207.3 C 41.9 184.4 42 161.7 42 138.7 C 42 121.8 36.5 96.1 45.2 81.3 C 51.3 70.9 50.4 75.9 58 79.2 C 67.5 83.4 70.7 82.8 80.4 79 C 114.7 65.7 149.9 35.5 188.7 41.1 C 211.7 44.5 221.2 57.5 226.2 79.1 C 228.8 90.1 230.1 101.6 231.8 112.9 C 234.7 132.3 233.3 154.3 238.8 173 C 246.5 199.5 258.6 237.3 252 265.8 C 248.9 279.6 231.6 278.3 219.1 279.8 C 191.1 283 164 287 135.8 287 C 109.3 287 75.5 292.8 50 285.3 C 38.6 281.9 31.7 275.2 33 263','fill':'#8dc63f','stroke':'#8dc63f','stroke-miterlimit':'10','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}];
        AvGen.paper = Raphael("avatarBox",300,300);
    },

    toolBox: function() {
       var moveRightBtn = $('#moveRightBtn');

        moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
            AvGen.paper.clear();
            AvGen.currSvg += 1;

            var svg = 'AvGen.svg' + AvGen.currSvg;
            console.log(svg); // <--- AvGen.svg1
            AvGen.paper.add(svg);
            // AvGen.paper.add(AvGen.svg1); <--- works
        });
    },
};
```

**EDIT:** I get no error what so ever in the console when clicking the button.

Comment: What is moveRightBtn element? Is it generated dynamically or after declaring this click handler?

Comment: When you call toolBox, is $('#moveRightBtn') already in DOM? I mean is alert($('#moveRightBtn').length); returning 1? BTW, you should tell us what means "it doesn't work". Errors in console or what???

Comment: If this line when uncommented works: AvGen.paper.add(AvGen.svg1);  forget about my previous comment

Comment: Yes, it's already in the DOM and yes AvGen.paper.add(AvGen.svg1); works. Updated the Q btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AvGen = {

    currSvg: 0,
    svg: [],

    init: function() {
        AvGen.loadSVG();
        AvGen.toolBox();
    },

    loadSVG: function() {
        AvGen.svg.push([0,0,255.3,298.5,{type:'path',path:'M 35.3 257.2 C 34.4 245.7 45.4 234.1 48.5 223 C 53.6 204.3 55 185 60 166.2 C 69.5 131 69.6 97.1 89.1 65.1 C 103.4 41.7 129.5 5.3 161.3 19.7 C 184.6 30.3 181.3 59.2 188.9 78.9 C 207.5 127.3 228.6 184.8 230.3 237.3 C 231.3 268.6 202.8 261.3 178.2 264 C 149.2 267.1 120 269.6 91 272.2 C 84.2 272.8 75.8 274.2 69 273 C 60.9 271.6 28.9 259.9 31.3 249.2','fill':'#39b54a','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}]);
        AvGen.svg.push([0,0,278.9,314.1,{type:'path',path:'M 32 265 C 31.8 245.2 38 226.9 39.8 207.3 C 41.9 184.4 42 161.7 42 138.7 C 42 121.8 36.5 96.1 45.2 81.3 C 51.3 70.9 50.4 75.9 58 79.2 C 67.5 83.4 70.7 82.8 80.4 79 C 114.7 65.7 149.9 35.5 188.7 41.1 C 211.7 44.5 221.2 57.5 226.2 79.1 C 228.8 90.1 230.1 101.6 231.8 112.9 C 234.7 132.3 233.3 154.3 238.8 173 C 246.5 199.5 258.6 237.3 252 265.8 C 248.9 279.6 231.6 278.3 219.1 279.8 C 191.1 283 164 287 135.8 287 C 109.3 287 75.5 292.8 50 285.3 C 38.6 281.9 31.7 275.2 33 263','fill':'#8dc63f','stroke':'#8dc63f','stroke-miterlimit':'10','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}]);
        AvGen.paper = Raphael("avatarBox",300,300);
    },

    toolBox: function() {

        moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
            AvGen.paper.clear();
            AvGen.currSvg += 1;

            var svg = AvGen.svg[AvGen.currSvg-1];
            AvGen.paper.add(svg);
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried it, but I get "TypeError: AvGen.svg is undefined" :/