# Change position and size of path

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, raphael, positioning

I'm using Raphael with JSON like this:

```
AvGen.svg1 = [0,0,255.3,298.5,
{type:'path',
path:'M 35.3 257.2 C 34.4 245.7 45.4 234.1 48.5 223 C 53.6 249.2',
'fill':AvGen.bodyColor,
'stroke':'none',
'stroke-width':'0',
'fill-opacity':'1',
'stroke-opacity':'0'}];
```

What I want is to position the path on a specific place within the Raphael object as well as change the size.

Unfortunately the Raphael documentation is horrible and I just can't figure out how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you fixed your previous issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032251/issue-with-dynamically-created-variables  ?

Comment: @roasted: No, unfortunately not. :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the `Element.transform()` [method](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform)? It can be a little tricky to deal with but it can scale and translate for you.

Based on the object you provided, you'll want something like this. (I arbitrarily chose a dark red for the fill color since that's a variable in your code, and changed the coordinates of the box for demo purposes.)

```
var svg = [10,30,255.3,298.5,
{type:'path',
path:'M 35.3 257.2 C 34.4 245.7 45.4 234.1 48.5 223 C 53.6 249.2',
'fill':"#900",
'stroke':'none',
'stroke-width':'0',
'fill-opacity':'1',
'stroke-opacity':'0'}];

var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var frame = paper.rect(svg[0], svg[1], svg[2], svg[3]);
var line = paper.path();

for (var prop in svg[4]) if (svg[4].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // if the key is a valid Raphael attribute, add it
    if (Raphael._availableAttrs.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        line.attr(prop, svg[4][prop]);    
    }
}
```

Then you can write a function to move the shape relative to the box and then scale it:

```
function moveShapeTo(box, shape, x, y, s) {
    console.log(shape.getBBox());
    //current upper-left corner of shape's bounding box
    var shape_xy = { x: shape.getBBox().x, y: shape.getBBox().y };

    // target location (coordinates relative to parent box)
    var target_xy = { x: box.getBBox().x + x, y: box.getBBox().y + y };    

    // how much to move the shape
    var offset = {
        x: target_xy.x - shape_xy.x,
        y: target_xy.y - shape_xy.y
    }

    shape.transform("T" + offset.x + "," + offset.y + " S" + s + "," + s + " " + target_xy.x + "," + target_xy.y);
}

moveShapeTo(box, line, 30, 50, 4);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/28fMw/2/)

Remember that the coordinates you give this function refer to the upper left corner of the shape's bounding box.